# Openssl encryption [Kotlin] [Android] (PHP)

Tags: java, php, android, kotlin

Using api I have to connect to PHP project with encrypted login and password in Kotlin.
I need to use the same secret password as I use in PHP, but have problem with generating Secret Key by following line:

```
val sk = SecretKeySpec(secretKey.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8),"AES_256") //here exception is throwing
val iv = IvParameterSpec(secretKey.substring(0, 16).toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
c.init(opmode, sk, iv)
```

That's my secret key: 
 `ksjdg*&%$dfgh"{#@!vcfkslc,.a/dcfxcsw345,45654gfdsgtrasd;fsdjf]}{O0-xfvbgdfeh=`

The problem is that exception is throwing about unsupported key size. I got it.

**But why using PHP and doing the same, using the same key, don't have any errors? :**

```
$encryptionKey = `ksjdg*&%$dfgh"{#@!vcfkslc,.a/dcfxcsw345,45654gfdsgtrasd;fsdjf]}{O0-xfvbgdfeh=`
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value, $encryptionMethod, $encryptionKey, 0, $iv);
```

What should do in Kotlin with my key to have it worked?

Comment: Do you really need to encrypt the data? Isn't it better to just use https instead, since that would encrypt the request anyway?

Comment: Yes unfortunately encryption is necessary...